# Convert Time to 0015 format Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

I want to Convert time to 0000 format. I'm using SQL Server 2017.

I've written the following query :

```
SELECT EventName, Convert(time, EventTime) as 'Log out' 
From AttendanceEvents
```

Which gives:

[image]

The Format I want my Time to be is :

```
1344
0032
1005
2013
```

and So on..

Comment: The `time` type doesn't *have* a format. So converting something *to* that type isn't going to do what you want. Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever 2017

Comment: Which DBMS? Are you using SSMS on a SQL Server database? Or Azure? Or another DBMS still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) third parameter set `108` will get a `hh:mi:ss` string, then get front 5 characters and `REPLACE` `:`.

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(5), EventTime, 108), ':', '')
```

or use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'hhmm')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'hhmm')

SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(5), GETDATE(), 108), ':', '')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/35564/1)**:

```
|      |
|------|
| 0718 |
```

Comment: Thanks! But what does this 108 implies?

Comment: @DawoodAbbas I add a link to msdn, `Convert` 108 will get a string `hh:mi:ss`